# Toggling between blocks

Tags: javascript, jsp

Why is this code not working and how to solve the one block is shown and some block is hide?

```
function vsd(){
    var asd = document.getElementById("asd");
    var vsd = document.getElementById("vsd");
    var psd = document.getElementById("psd");
    var vps = document.getElementById("vps");
    var asp = document.getElementById("asp");
    var vsp = document.getElementById("vsp");
    var sad = document.getElementById("sad");
    if (vsd.style.display === "none") {
        vsd.style.display ="block";
        asd.style.display = "none"; 
        psd.style.display = "none";
        vps.style.display = "none";
        asp.style.display = "none";
        vsp.style.display = "none";
        sad.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        vsd.style.display = "none";}
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that vsd is in display:none mode at load time and in the else statement think to show back psd, vsd blah

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced your approach with a  `css` class `hide`

```js
window.onload = vsd();

function vsd(){
    var asd = document.getElementById("asd");
    var vsd = document.getElementById("vsd");
    var psd = document.getElementById("psd");
    var vps = document.getElementById("vps");
    var asp = document.getElementById("asp");
    var vsp = document.getElementById("vsp");
    var sad = document.getElementById("sad");
    console.log($("#vsd")[0].attr('style'))
    if (vsd.classList.contains("hide") {
        vsd.classList -= "hide";
        asd.classList += "hide";
        psd.classList += "hide";
        vps.classList += "hide";
        asp.classList += "hide";
        vsp.classList += "hide";
        sad.classList += "hide";
    } else {
        vsd.classList += "hide";
    }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<button id="vsd" class="">vsd</button>
<button id="asd" class="hide">asd</button>
<button id="psd" class="hide">psd</button>
<button id="vps" class="hide">vps</button>
<button id="asp" class="hide">asp</button>
<button id="vsp" class="hide">vsp</button>
<button id="sad" class="hide">sad</button>
```